# PHP Webservice returning empty result

Tags: php, mysql, web-services

Hi I am trying to fetch list of videos path from MySQL db. But i am not getting any error and response is empty with status code is 200.

Here is my get_all_videos.php code

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST');
header('Content-Type: application/json');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization');
require_once 'include/DB_Functions.php';
$db = new DB_Functions();

$response = array("status" => 1);


$videos = $db -> getAllVideos();
if ($videos) {
    $response["status"] = 0;
    $response["videos"] = $videos;
    $response["message"] = "Videos details fetch successfully";
    echo json_encode($response);
} else {
    $response["status"] = 1;
    $response["message"] = "Unknown error occurred in getting details!";
    echo json_encode($response);
}   

?>
```

Here is db function

```
/**
 * Get all videos
 */ 
public function getAllVideos(){
    $videos = array();
    if ($result = $this->conn->query("SELECT * FROM tbl_videos")) {
        /* fetch associative array */
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

            $row_array["tbl_videos_id"] = $row['tbl_videos_id'];
            $row_array["video_path"] = $row['video_path'];
            $row_array["title"] = $row['title'];
            $row_array["description"] = $row['description'];
            $row_array["video_cover_path"] = $row['video_cover_path'];

            array_push($videos, $row_array);
        }

        /* free result set */
        $result->free();
        return $videos;
    }
}
```

But I am getting always empty result. I checked in DB and used select query but in phpmyadmin i am able to get records.

Comment: Have you checked for db errors?

Comment: it's not showing any error. if status 500 then only error are getting logged. but status is 200 with no response

Comment: Have you debugged the results of your query? No contents in the table? Tried the query directly in the DB (via PHPMyAdmin or alike)?

Comment: Yes, query returning result in phpmyadmin.

Comment: We can't debug it for you. Setup a debugger or do it with `die` and `var_dump`.